# Space between handler and content in a SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, android-sdk-1.6

When I try to use a SlidingDrawer in the horizontal orientation I get a space between the handler and the content. Any idea how I can get rid of it? In the vertical orientation I do not get a space.

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/module_trafic_map_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:topOffset="0dp"
    android:bottomOffset="0dp"
    android:handle="@+id/module_trafic_map_handle"
    android:content="@+id/module_trafic_map_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/module_trafic_map_handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/trafic_info_popup_right"
    />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/module_trafic_map_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
    />
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the SlidingDrawer width to match_parent?

Comment: Changing the layout_width to match_parent does not get rid of the gap between the handler and the content.

Comment: I do not know if it helps, but I wanted to add that the SlidingDrawer is in the content of a TabView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try android:scaleType="center" in your ImageView.

Comment: perfect, it solved my problem (even if I'm not one who asked the question)

Comment: I accept the answer as it solved the problem for DallaRosa. I moved on with my project and didn't use a SlidingDrawer.